# how to add files to the project namespace in visual studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, windows-mobile

i am having a problem in adding the image files to project namespace. I'm trying to do this like........

Step 1:Going to add existing item menu.

Step 2:Then browsing to the file that i want to add and simply adding it.

But when I'm trying to read this file by this method-------

```
Assembly myAssembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
Stream myStream = myAssembly
        .GetManifestResourceStream("namespace.filename.fileExtension");
img = new Bitmap(myStream);
```

I get null in myStream. I think there is some other way to add files to the namespace of the project because previously I have added some files and the same method is working for those files.

Anybody knowing the answer please help.

Rregards,
Madhup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you marked those files to be an embedded resource (solution explorer)? Also - try it without the extension. You can use `GetManifestResourceNames` to check what is available.

Comment: thanks for the help. i found out this to be mine silly mistake that cost me one day of effort wasted. i wish i do no forget it again.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need to set the compile-property of the file to 'embedded resource'. You find this propert by selecting th file in the solution explorer and then go to the properties window (F4).

Comment: thanks for the help. i found out this to be mine silly mistake that cost me one day of effort wasted. i wish i do no forget it again.